# How to append list in for loop in python

Tags: python

I spend several hours on this and yet I'm unable to understand what is going on. In my belief this would work in other languages (e.g. Javascript), but in Python I don't know what is going on.

I am using a simple MongoDB DataStructure that consists of

field1: "value1"
field2: "value2"
fieldn: "valuen"
fieldM: Array

and the target is to print out every value of the array along with its "parent". The Python function I have written for this purpose looks like this

```
def manageonts(sProj):
    ontologies = []
    my_ontology = OntologyDefinition()
    for o in OntologyDefinition.GetAll(sProj): #parent items 
        for l in o.OntologyDefinitions: #child items
            my_ontology.a_type = l[0] #we can access the fields of the array via this method
            my_ontology.a_text = l[1]
            my_ontology.a_subtopic = l[2]
            my_ontology.a_weight = l[3]
            my_ontology.a_weight_if_referenced = l[4]
            ontologies.append(my_ontology)
    for ont in ontologies:
        print(ont.a_text)
```

while OntologyDefinition is a class that has fields for every "column", including the fields of the array.

I would assume that the last loop would return results such as

```
database
date
data
datum
design
event
figure
```

But instead it seems like the `ontologies` list contains only the *last* value:

```
capacity
capacity
capacity
capacity
capacity
capacity
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am particularly interested why this behaviour happens. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this line:

```
my_ontology = OntologyDefinition()
```

inside the `for` loops.  Otherwise you are only creating one OntologyDefinition and referencing it many times, overwriting its values every time through the loop.